# How can I set up nodejs and express as a docker container on digital ocean?

Tags: node.js, express, docker, digital-ocean

I have tried to get this working but I am struggling to expose the node app on port 80. Also I want to be sure ever thing else is secure.

**UPDATE:**

*Trying to be more clear...*
I am using this Dockerfile

```
FROM node:argon

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 8888
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

Then I use this command to start the container

```
$ docker run -p 8888:80 christmedical/christ-medical-server
```

from my docker public IP I get nothing

Comment: Could you be more specific about the steps you're taking and the issue you're facing?

Comment: Thanks! updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In docker run reference [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/), in the expose port section says:

> -p=[]      : Publish a container᾿s port or a range of ports to the host
>                  format: ip:hostPort:containerPort | ip::containerPort | hostPort:containerPort | containerPort

If you say you want to access it on port 80 of your host so this should be your command:

```
docker run -p 80:8888 christmedical/christ-medical-server
```